# Convert string array to custom object list using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class with one public property.

```
public class CustomEntity 
{
    string _FileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _FileName; }
        set
        {                    
           _FileName = value;

        }
    }

}
```

I have array of string which I want to convert in List of "CustomEntity" using linq.
please suggest me how I can do that.

Comment: Well, how much research have you done? What's the purpose of your Instance property (which confusingly will return a new instance on each call)? Note that not having an accessible constructor will mean you can't use object initializers.

Comment: You can do it exactly how you said, using LINQ. Everything you need can be found with some effort on your side. We won't code it for you. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use Linq's Select extension and ToList to convert the IEnumerable (from Select extension) to a list

An Example:

```
string[] randomArray = new string[3] {"1", "2", "3"};
List<CustomEntity> listOfEntities = randomArray.Select(item => new CustomEntity() { FileName = item } ).ToList();
```

Comment: wouldn't it be sufficient  enough to use just:    List<CustomEntity> = randomArray.ToList()